# Specify default figure label in Matlab

Tags: matlab, handle, figure, axis-labels

Almost all my plots have 'time' on the (horizontal) x-axis, so I was wondering if I could change the label to read 'Time [sec]' by default.

I have been looking into the `get(groot,'factoryAxes')` properties and it seems I can change the Xlabel with `get(groot,'defaultAxesXlabel')`. However, when I change it to `set(groot,'defaultAxesXlabel','Time [sec]')` I get an error:

```
Error using gca
While setting the 'Parent' property of Axes:
Value must be a handle.

Error in newplot (line 68)
    ax = gca(fig);
```

Is this the right approach? Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: Interesting question. I guess you are using R2014b or later. In those versions the `'Xlabel'` property of the axes is not a string anymore, but a _text object_. One possible approach would be something like `set(groot,'defaultFigureCreateFcn', 'xlabel(''time [sec]'')')` or `set(groot,'defaultAxesCreateFcn', 'xlabel(''time [sec]'')')`, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Yes, I'm using R2014b. I've also tried your approach but it didn't work for me either. So we're still left with the same problem. I've also posted this question in the Mathworks User Community but haven't received an answer yet